# Global section of tensor product

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

suppose $C$ is a smooth projective curve. $L$ is a line bundle with a non zero global section $s$. Suppose $L_0$ is another line bundle but of degree zero.

Assume $dimH^0(L)=dimH^0(L\otimes L_0)$. Does $s$ correspond to a canonical section of $L\otimes L_0$ ?

Comment: Cross posted http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499525/global-section-of-tensor-product

Answer (score 4):

No reason for that. If $L$ and $L_0$ are generic (given their degrees), then the equality of dimensions will hold. But there is no reason to have a natural isomorphism of spaces of sections.